# Bivariate in R (mvtnorm package)

Tags: r, pdf

I have two normal r.v.'s that are independent of each other (so the correlation $\rho= 0$).  The two r.v.'s come from the following two Normal distributions, i.e.,  $X\sim N(18, 5.7)$ and $Y\sim N(12.72, 30.38)$.

I want to calculate $Pr(X>10, Y<10)$. Of course, as they are independent, I can calculate the product of the marginal density and the result should be $Pr(X>10, Y<10) = Pr(X>10)\times Pr(Y<10)=0.3106$.

However, I'm starting to learn how to use the `mvtnorm` package in `R` and,according to this article https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/vignettes/MVT_Rnews.pdf, this is how you should solve the problem:

```
> library(mvtnorm)
> m<-2
> corr<-diag(2)
> corr[2,1]<-0
> pmvnorm(mean=c(18,12.72),corr,lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(+Inf,10))
```

but the result is: 0.003264096

Where is the error in my logic?

Comment: I see no references to "5.7" or "30.38" in your code, so how can it possibly return the answer you expect?  (If these are intended to be standard deviations, then you must supply them as arguments to `pmvnorm`.)

Comment: Also calculating $P(X>x, Y<y)$ is obviously *not* the same as $P(X<x, Y<y)$ (bivariate CDF)...

Comment: @whuber In fact it sounds me strange but I've followed the article I cited and both sd and variance are not mentioned..

Comment: They *are* mentioned: see Section 1, *A Simple Example.* Better yet, see the help page for `pmvnorm`.

Comment: Thank you!but if anything I miss,in the example mentioned there are references on correlation matrix but not on variance and covariance..

Comment: @whuber I think I edited the question such that it should be within the rules. Please consider re-opening.

Comment: @Andrea I would post this as a solution but since whuber closed it I cannot.  So here is the solution to the problem. 

`library(mvtnorm);

mu = c(18,12.72);
covariance = diag(c(5.7,30.38),2);
X = c(10,-Inf);
Y = c(Inf,10);

pmvnorm(mean=mu,sigma=covariance,lower=X,upper=Y)`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the above solution, I wasn't able to post it with multiple lines.  However, your mistake, as @whuber tried to point out, is that you are not telling `R` anything about your variances (i.e., 5.7 or 30.38).  So instead of using a correlation matrix, just specify the covariance matrix instead. If your covariance matrix has 0's on the off diagonals, then it is implied in this situation that your two r.v.'s are independent.

Comment: @ZERO This question is definitely off-topic here on CV.  I'll migrate it so you can post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were forgetting to include the variance of your random variables.  Instead of specifying the correlation matrix, just specify the covariance matrix. Here is the `R` code to do it:

```
library(mvtnorm)

   mu = c(18,12.72)
   covariance = diag(c(5.7,30.38),2)
   X = c(10,-Inf)
   Y = c(Inf,10)

   pmvnorm(mean=mu,sigma=covariance,lower=X,upper=Y)
```